# Gurobi binary MVar, no diagonal connections between 1s

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, solver, gurobi

I'm writing a MIP optimization model with gurobipy and I have this n*n matrix of boolean decision variables called "delivery_order". The matrix is such that:

- the diagonal only contains zeros (it can actually contain anything, I used 0s for simplicity);
- there is no fixed limit to the number of 1s it can contain, since we imagine to "connect" the ones, they represent a path (namely the position [i,j] of the matrix can be seen as "i'm going from the point i to the point j in the real world").

With that being said, there are only two constraints the matrix must fulfill:

1. the first one simply says that there must be at least 2 1s distributed between the column zero and the row zero of the matrix delivery_order: `model.addConstr(sum(delivery_order[0, :], delivery_order[0, :]) >= 2)`. This is working.
2. The second one is more complicated, it says that there must exist at least one path between the 1s in the matrix such that if we link these 1s with an imaginary line there cannot be diagonals. In the following image I show you what I mean:
   [no diagonals VS diagonal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj5Q8.jpg)

I don't know how to tell the guroby solver that the matrix must respect this second condition, I already tried by summing rows and/or columns, but as I told you there is no limit to the number of 1s in the matrix, so it didn't really work. I found on internet that I could use support variables of some kind, but I don't know how.
Thank you in advance for the help.

I already tried by summing and by checking the parity of rows and columns. I also tried to look for methods that implied matrix multiplication but nothing worked, most of the time the program returned an error.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because optimization modeling belongs on or.stackexchange.com